# Command to start nodejs? Server.js and app.js missing

Tags: javascript

The outdated documentation for drupal integration of nodejs using the nodejs module instructs me to start  nodejs with the command `node server.js`.

But neither server.js or app.js (replacement to server.js) exists

I can see a file called nodejs.js but running `node nodejs.js` produces this error;

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/data/disk/o1/static/hood-7.43.1/sites/all/modules/nodejs/nodejs.js:132:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

What is the command for starting nodejs?

Comment: `What is the command for starting nodejs?` it's `node server.js`

Comment: Follow this [for Drupal 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znr0aFOlDnI) OR [for Drupal 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1sxDaH3Z-U). They are different, so make sure you follow the correct version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had incorrectly upgraded the 7.x-1.10 module incorrectly. From version 7.x-1.1 you can no longer merely overwrite the old module with the new module as the installation process is different.

Answer (score 1):

If you're downloading the app from [github](https://github.com/beejeebus/drupal-nodejs) directly, follow these instructions:

1. Download the archive
2. Extract to a folder oustide of Drupal's root (this app is separate to your Drupal installation so shouldn't be within)
3. `cd` to the folder and run `npm install`
4. Run `cp nodejs.config.js.example nodejs.config.js`, edit the resulting file as required
5. Run `node app.js`

Voila, server up and running.

If you're using the `npm install drupal-node.js` approach, the instructions are a bit unclear. To clarify:

1. Create a folder outside of the Drupal root
2. `cd` to it and run `npm install drupal-node.js`
3. Run `cp node_modules/drupal-node.js/nodejs.config.js.example nodejs.config.js`, edit as required
4. Run `node node_modules/drupal-node.js/app.js` to start the server

You should see the same result as the first method.

Comment: app.js does not exist and neither does the node node_modules/drupal-node.js/app.js path

Comment: I tried both of those methods, they both work fine. You might need to start again from scratch

Comment: I'm using the "forever" keep  alive startup service. Would that change things at all?

Comment: Shouldn't do, but consult the docs just in case